# Get partial file name by split

Tags: c#, string, filenames

I have the following file names:

```
1_2_firstname_00b32acd-1234-4567-12345678900_1597932388.zip
1_2_firstname_00b32ace-1234-4568-12345678900_1597932318_id.zip
1_2_firstname_00b32acf-1234-4557-12345678900_id_1597932358_id2.zip
1_2_firstname_00b32ccg-1234-4167-12345678900_1597932331_id_id2_id3.zip
```

In some case my file contains id and sometimes no.

What is the best way to get only the partial file name

```
 1_2_firstname_00b32acd-1234-4567-12345678900
 1_2_firstname_00b32acf-1234-4557-12345678900
 1_2_firstname_00b32ccg-1234-4167-12345678900
```

without get the other string?

Comment: If it is always the same length, you can use `Substring(0, 53)`.

Comment: after the last edit, your post is inconclusive. Where did the `lastname` go? you still expect it as result

Comment: I'm sorry, because lastname its cant be random..

Comment: " because lastname its cant be random" then try to specify it a little more precisely. does it contain only letters? because all these things matter. how big is the variety of the characters in `lastname`? please give some examples.

Comment: please edit again. what should be matched here: `1_2_firstname_00b32acf-1234-4557-88886888883_id_1597932358_id2.zip` ? and what should be matched here: `1_2_firstname_00b32ccg-1234-4167-88884888884_1597932331_id_id2_id3.zip` what is your expected result?

Comment: edit again, thanks!

Comment: @yaakovyaakov I edited my answer according to your new version. Have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex for it:

```
List<string> allFileNames = new List<string>
{
    "1_2_firstname_00b32acd-1234-4567-12345678900_1597932388.zip",
    "1_2_firstname_00b32ace-1234-4568-12345678900_1597932318_id.zip",
    "1_2_firstname_00b32acf-1234-4557-12345678900_id_1597932358_id2.zip",
    "1_2_firstname_00b32ccg-1234-4167-12345678900_1597932331_id_id2_id3.zip",
};

string pattern =  @".*?\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{11}";

foreach (var element in allFileNames.Select(x => Regex.Match(fileName, pattern).Value))
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

Output:

> 1_2_firstname_00b32ccg-1234-4167-12345678900
> 1_2_firstname_00b32ccg-1234-4167-12345678900
> 1_2_firstname_00b32ccg-1234-4167-12345678900
> 1_2_firstname_00b32ccg-1234-4167-12345678900

Explanation:

`.*?` matches any character (non-greedy)

`\d{4}` matches exactly 4 occurences of a digit

`-` matches `-`

`\d{11}` matches exactly 11 occurences of a digit

Comment: sorry I have been edited my question because lastname isnt always the same, its could be also timestamp.. sorry about the edit!

Comment: @yaakovyaakov ok but what do you expect to match? would you please make the edit coherent?

Comment: Might better fit his inputs with `.*\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{11}` as it sounds like "lastname" and "firstname" aren't literal though this too might not work if the number lengths are variable.

Comment: @McAden I was just writing this new pattern when the door rang :D some dude tried to sell me a new phone contract. anoying